# Project created with maven-archetype-webapp does not found servlet

Tags: java, jsp, maven, servlets, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans to start a new application that will runs in Glassfish.

I used the Netbeans wizard to create a new projet using the maven-archetype-webapp and put all my classes under `src->main->resources` and my JSP files under `src->main->webapp`

This is my `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <display-name>My Applicaton Name</display-name>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Access</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.company.department.controller.UserController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Access</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Access</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is the `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MyApp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
      <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
      <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.apache.commons.fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2.LIFERAY-PATCHED-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20141113</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>MyApp</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run it in my localhost I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.department.controller.UserController`

I'm new on Maven, so where is my mistake?

I found some similar problems here in SO, but no solution solved the problem and the most of them are directed for Eclipse and apparently exists some differences in NetBeans.

Comment: you dont put your classes under src/main/resources, that folder is for resources ;) , you put them under src/main/java, and if using netbeans as you say, netbeans will show you a difference between ```source packages``` and ```other sources```

Comment: Thx @maress. Oddly, the java folder is not automatically created by Netbeans. Anyway, I created the folder, but neither worked. See part of the stacktrace:

`WebModule[/MyApp]Error loading WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/) com.company.department.controller.UserController
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.department.controller.UserController
 at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)`

Comment: if you created the maven project using netbeans, it will always create the source package correctly. And you need to add scope at provided for the javaee dependency. Also javaee defines something called ```javaee-endorsed-api```, which you specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a snippet for your maven pom file.
Make sure the following is as provided.

```
<properties>
   <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                <silent>true</silent>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>javax</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                        <version>7.0</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```